# Add user to domain via local admin?

Tags: cmd.exe, administrator, domain

I tried connecting a few PCs to a domain and they all seem to be accessible, however there are no accounts on the domain. How do I add user to a domain using local admin cmd?

Comment: How is this different from your question yesterday (the marked possible duplicate)?